# Telegram bot - add unique key to /start command

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to identify each user by some unique key, which is added to `/start` command. For each user, I will generate some key, and show URL to the user. This is described step by step in the official documentation [https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking%C2%A8)

Link for the users is in the format:

https://telegram.me/ExampleBot?start=uniqueKey

It works perfectly in the telegram app. The probem is, that when opened in the browser, only button "Start" is visible. When the user clicks, the `uniqueKey` is not send to the bot.

**How to add a uniqueKey to /start command to make it work in telegram web app too? How should look like the generated URL?** So user can just click, and does not need to write the code?

Comment: You can't create bot without a Human account. And every account can only have **20 bots** quota.

Comment: Thanks, that what I was afraid of. So I need to use https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api instead of telegram bot api?

Comment: Make your `uniqueKey` as `Base64` and test again.

Comment: Looks like, it works :-), thanks, just need to do more tests! Now I see, it's stated in the documentation "We recommend using base64url to encode parameters with binary and other types of content."

Comment: @RAM post it as an answer, I will then accept the answer and give you the bounty

Comment: @PetrAdam, I'm happy that it worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `uniqueKey` as `Base64` and test again...

> Based on **[Telegram documents](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking)** it is recommended to using **base64url** to encode parameters with binary and other types of content.